# Sticking things to Walls in 3D

Tags: 3d, software-engineering, 3d-meshes

I'm trying to leave the second dimension and finally make a 3d game, but I'm having a hard time coming up with a way to implement a certain concept. I am trying to make a flat object which would "stick to walls." It's a bit difficult to explain, so I'll just add a picture here.
[image]
The way I see it, there are a few parts to this problem. Firstly, how would I specify which edge on one polygon leads to an edge on another?
Secondly, how would I make sure that the object never gets excessively deformed when on a corner of 3 or more edges? (As in, how do I assure the gaussian curvature always stays as 0) And thirdly, how would I split the object along the two surfdaces it's on without having a ton of polygons?

I'm not sure what engine I'll be programming this in yet, because as I said, it's my first foray into 3d, so if responses could either just explain concepts or use pseudocode, that would be optimal, but if you want to use examples from a specific language it'll work.

Thanks in advance for anyone who wants to respond!

Comment: You should start with something simpler if you start 3d

Comment: Most games don't actually do this, take Portal 2 as an example. They had gel physics in that game, but it wouldn't wrap around corners.

Answer (score 1):

A popular technique to handle this is called projection. Shadow mapping and decal placement are popular use cases of this.

A few good tutorials are on http://rastertek.com/tutdx11.html (see shadow mapping and projective texturing)
[How do I create a decal system?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24653/how-do-i-create-a-decal-system) for more info

Comment: The projections warp shapes as they're projected onto objects, allowing for distortion, but I'm looking for something more like a sheet of paper or some other thin material sliding over an object.

Comment: ah you mean more a physics sim. So you could definitely use this technique  to create a moving object that simply follows a path along the stairs (or whatever you want) and project it on there. You can do some more math to keep it from shrinking/growing (reverse/ignore depth).

Another option is to create a primitive fluid sim where you have a bunch of voxels/blobs following a path and just hug the surface under them